# Exception while reading file from HDFS (Hortonworks Sandbox) using Java API

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sandbox, java, file-read

I'm facing problems while trying to read a file from HDFS (Hortonworks Sandbox) using Java API. Following is my code -

```
    System.setProperty ("hadoop.home.dir", "/");
    URI uri = URI.create ("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/maria_dev/test.txt");

    Path path = new Path (uri);

    Configuration conf = new Configuration ();
    conf.set ("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:8020");
    conf.set ("dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname","true");
    conf.set("dfs.datanode.use.datanode.hostname","true");
    conf.set("dfs.client.use.legacy.blockreader", "true");

    byte[] btbuffer = new byte[5];
    String s;
    try (FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get (uri, conf)) {
        try {
            FSDataInputStream fileIn = fs.open (path);
            //s = fileIn.readUTF ();
            fileIn.read (btbuffer, 0, 20); 
            s = new String (btbuffer, Charset.forName ("UTF-8"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err){
        err.printStackTrace ();
    }
```

Following are the exceptions I'm getting -

```
10:39:51.803 [main] WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory - I/O error constructing remote block reader. java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused .   
10:39:51.803 [main] WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - Failed to connect to sandbox.hortonworks.com/172.17.0.2:50010 for block, add to deadNodes and continue. java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused .   
10:39:51.804 [main] INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - Could not obtain BP-1464254149-172.17.0.2-1477381671113:blk_1073742576_1752 from any node: java.io.IOException: No live nodes contain block BP-1464254149-172.17.0.2-1477381671113:blk_1073742576_1752 after checking nodes = [172.17.0.2:50010], ignoredNodes = null No live nodes contain current block Block locations: 172.17.0.2:50010 Dead nodes:  172.17.0.2:50010.
```

Couldn't find any working solution. Any help is appreciated.

Edited :
The following are the entries of the /etc/hosts of my host system(from where I'm calling the job)-

```
127.0.0.1       localhost    
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost    
::1             localhost    
172.17.0.2 sandbox.hortonworks.com localhost
```

Comment: check `hostname` and match the fs.defaultFS with that.

Comment: hostname is sandbox.hortonworks.com. Changing the fs.defaultFS to sandbox.hortonworks.com doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Where are you running this code? The sandbox has no UI, so are you writing this in the terminal? Changing configuration settings **within** the sandbox should not be done. Those are fine.

Comment: I'm running it from the host machine and not the VM. Do you mean the conf.set in my code isn't fine?

Comment: did u solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This is you mentioned URI `URI uri = URI.create ("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/maria_dev/test.txt");`

But it is trying to reach `sandbox.hortonworks.com`

Try by changing the URI

Comment: changed the URI to sandbox.hortonworks.com, but got this exception - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: sandbox.hortonworks.com

Comment: Can you post your /etc/hosts entries

Comment: The file at the given URI is being opened but the read is not happening. So I'm guessing the problem might not be with the URI.

Comment: Here are the /etc/hosts entries - `127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback      
fe00::0 ip6-localnet          
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix      
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes .     
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2      sandbox.hortonworks.com`

Comment: Is it the last line `172.17.0.2 sandbox.hortonworks.com` if yes add `localhost` to the same line and try

Comment: When you say /etc/hosts is it in the VM or in the host system?

Comment: If you are submitting job from VM it's VM hosts file otherwise host `hosts` file

Comment: These are the entries of the host's etc/hosts - `127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost` When I added the line `172.17.0.2 sandbox.hortonworks.com localhost` I get a new exception - `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory - I/O error constructing remote block reader.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

Comment: Is it warning or error, if possible update your post with new details

Comment: @MK22 you need to edit the hosts file of the host machine running the sandbox, not the sandbox itself, probably

Comment: Ya. Edited in the host machine itself now. Edited my question with the new errors.